# How to present AmpieChart tilte in two line

Tags: java, amcharts

I want Slice title in two line such as Czech Republic I need
Czech 
Republic
I have tried  but it seems to be not working in my case. I have small space to display chart

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "pie",  
"theme": "none",
"legend": {
    "markerType": "circle",
    "position": "right",
    "marginRight": 80,      
    "autoMargins": false
},
"dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 256.9
}, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 131.1
}, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 115.8
}, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 109.9
}, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 108.3
}, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 65
}, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 40
}],
"valueField": "litres",
"titleField": "country",
 "titleField": "country"
"balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
"exportConfig": {
    "menuTop":"0px",
    "menuItems": [{
        "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
        "format": 'png'
    }]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can either define the line break in your data-provider like this:

```
"dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Czech<br>Republic",
    "litres": 256.9
}
```

or you just could get the labels inside the pie using the labeladius-property:

```
"labelRadius": -35
```

You can play around with the labelRadius in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/rM8j6/light/) and see how it works.
Docs for this is [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelRadius).